# How to avoid manually reinstalling zfs after kernel update

Tags: kernel, zfs, dkms

I use ZFS and everytime the kernel is updated, ZFS is broken and the mounts are missing. I always have to follow this procedure, that I found on the net (https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/1155):

```
dkms remove -m zfs -v 0.6.4.2 --all
dkms remove -m spl -v 0.6.4.2 --all
dkms add -m spl -v 0.6.4.2
dkms add -m zfs -v 0.6.4.2
dkms install -m spl -v 0.6.4.2
```

Last command always leads to error in which case I have to run:

```
apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-3.13.0-62 linux-headers-3.13.0-62-generic
```

I also have to be careful to get the right versions each time. Which makes it even more painful.

This happens on nearly each system update that I run. I did have to tell my wife not to update, as this would most likely shut her out of the system.
I hoped this to be a bug, that gets resolved, but its like this since a year now. I could not find a way to solve this permanently, is there?

I use Kubuntu amd64 14.04

```
uname -a
Linux 3.13.0-62-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:29:36 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm fairly new to Linux so please be gentle :)

**Update:** Modified the header version, to be in line with my uname output.

Also yes, I did not run dkms install -m zfs -v 0.6.4.2 since the command before already lead to an error. I understand that the "add" command in combination of an reinstall of the header has the same effect. I will test this next time anyway.

**Update2:** Some additional bit of information. The default installation created a boot partition which is ridiculous small (230mb) and I try to not forget to clean it up from time to time but I have had several incidents where the update might not have enough space on the boot partiton to complete without error. I have absolutely no clue how dangerous this is and if my system is already long ago corrupted due to that. Since it happens so easily I hope its not a big deal thoug.

**Update3:** This problem slvoed itself over time I guess this was a bug that got fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a package of zfs thats maintained faster, i.e. each release of the kernel, the maintainer is on it, and updates his code base for the new kernel right away.

Using arch linux, you will see that demizer updates the zfs-linux-git pretty much within a few days of the kernel being updated, which at that is always bleeding edge so he has his work cut out for himself for e.g.

Using LTS packages, you will might see these problems compounded since LTS means to upgrade kernels sparingly, which is what leads to this issue in the first place.

The best thing to do aside from that is to each time you update your system, when it warns you about the zfs, just wait and DONT update that day, and keep trying your update daily until the maintainer finally has released the new version when it no longer issues the warning.  If you practice this, your kernel will stay as updated as your zfs allows it, being at the mercy of your zfs package maintainer, and you will not have to ever rebuild zfs yourself, which is kind of a pain.

Comment: Luckily ZFS is now part of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS :). This really seams like a suboptimal solution... Shouldn't kernel update in this case be blocked until all such packages are updated? Or was tehre really a warning that gets ignored by default? I don't remember being warned and asked if I want to proceed anyway.

Comment: ok, so your  Ubuntu is LTS, ok i was initially thinking zfs-lts, yeah for Ubuntu LTS yes, your correct.  

So yeah if your using "Ubuntu LTS", that means you need to NOT update your ZFS  pretty much, until it matches your LTS kernel update, just teh same, or not until you update your entire LTS version, in the LTS manner of things.  Its wierd that didnt see any warning  messages though.     

Also note doing it your way, its easy to introduce a problem when compiling as well, plus a pain.  Can you move off LTS? If your tech savvy, move to something more updated to suit your usage..

Comment: No, you got me wrong. When I had this problem I was on still on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS where ZFS was installed by me. Your answer was spot on I think. 
But inbetween I switched to 16.04 LTS and there ZFS is already shipped with Ubuntu and nicely integrated. So my problem is gone for good.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `linux-headers-generic` package is not installed.

That is why `linux-headers` do not update with `linux-image`.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

and you will always have the correct headers.

Comment: Hmm, I get an error on install spl, so I stopped there. Is this really it, do I have to run both even though they throw errors? I will definitely try (and feel stupid afterwards). Unfortunately I have to wait for the next update to confirm your answer.

Comment: It depends on which errors appear.

Comment: I just run `dkms install -m zfs -v 0.6.4.2` and it outputted `Module zfs/0.6.4.2 already installed on kernel 3.13.0-62-generic/x86_64` so I have my doubts that your answer is correct. But we'll see.

Comment: This question is almost off topic. You better ask this at github.

Comment: Btw, ofc 'I have installed the right header version. Thats why I said "with updated versions" But I will update the question to be less confusing.

Comment: Sorry, seems to have not changed a thing:
`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.`

Comment: That is weird. If this package is installed, it should pull the latest headers.